# Detect when the TinyMCE text editor is ready(after initialization)

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

Since it takes some time to load up the tinyMCE text editor, I use **useEffect**, **useRef** hooks to detect when the text editor is ready and will probably update the state to render the editor rather than spinner. However, **useEffect** isn't invoked even after the initialization(***editorRef.current*** is being watched over).
Is there anything wrong with this approach?

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Editor } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";

export default function App() {
  const editorRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("editor is ready")
  }, [editorRef.current]);
  return (
    <>
      <Editor
        onInit={(evt, editor) => (editorRef.current = editor)}
        initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor.</p>"
        init={{
          height: 500,
          menubar: false,
          plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount",
          ],
          toolbar:
            "undo redo | formatselect | " +
            "bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter " +
            "alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | " +
            "removeformat | help",
          content_style:
            "body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }",
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a state to store the editor object got from the onInit method parameter.

Set this state as a dependency in a useEffect hook.

In the onInit method, call the setState hook.

See extract code below:

```
const [editor, setEditor] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(editor);
}, [editor]);

return (
    <Editor
        onInit={(evt, editor) => {
            setEditor(editor);
            editorRef.current = editor;
        }}
    />
);
```